# SQL Server - Low CPU workload but waiting tasks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have a SQL Server 2016 with 8 CPU cores and 32GB of RAM. User complain now and then about our slow applications but we can never understand it. So I try to find possible weak spots.

CPU workload of the SQL Server is most of the time by 1%-20%. 
But sometimes i have 30-50 waiting Tasks.

Could this be a Problem?

- MAXDOP ist set to 0 (use all cores)
- Cost Threshold of Parallelism is set to 5

[Here are my wait statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xpO2.png)

Are my CXPACKET waits to high? Should I change my MAXDOP and Threshold Settings?
Or would you say that my SQL Server looks healthy?

Comment: This may help: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/08/what-is-the-cxpacket-wait-type-and-how-do-you-reduce-it/ - *the short story is that you should set it to the number of cores in one processor, up to 8.*

Comment: And the IO? I'll bet it's rather high, which results in delays and CXPACKET waits. No matter how fast the CPU, it can't do anything if the disk is slow. CXPACKET is a symptom of slow IO, not the cause. Reducing the DOP will reduce the CXPACKET waits only because fewer cores will wait for the same IO to complete

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: "CXPACKET is a symptom of slow IO". I challenge that assertion. There are a lot of things that could cause a thread to wait on parallelism. One example is that the data histogram doesn't reflect the actual data distribution and as a result one thread is given a lot more work than the others. The other threads will finish "early" and wait for the overworked one to finish, accruing CXPACKET waits the whole time.

Comment: @BenThul it's not an assertion. When information is missing, one can only guess. IO is more likely to cause delays *and* result in a lot of CXPACKET waits. We need *at least* the IO load and the CPU at the time of the waits. If it's ~12.5% then yes, it's all cores waiting for one . I'd bet on high IO though

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the io to the CPU's did you use auto processor Affinity CPU and IO ?   or did you do processor Affinity manually ?

How many CPU cores are licensed?

Do you have statistics on Memory usage and % processor usage for each separate CPU ?

And last yes IO would be the last issue on drives, do you have file groups with as many files as your MaxDop x2 ?

MAXDOP could be limited to the number of cores you have in a single CPU is a standard recommendation.  Also there is an advanced setting for the cost before parellelizim defaults to cost of 5 that is no longer a valid default should be moved to 50 to 200 for the min cost before you parallelize.

Do you have one core set aside for Windows operations and if SSIS/SSAS is used one or more for those too, and/or is boost SQL server priority not checked?